# Spin wheel in dojo framework

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget, loading, dojox.charting

I have a piece of code

`this.domNode.classList.add('widget-loading');`

which is adding a spin wheel. Now I want to sustain the spin wheel for 10 seconds.
I tried the below which dint work.

```
setTimeout(function(){ this.domNode.classList.add('widget-loading')},10000);
```

Could anyone help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi , could you describe exactly the problem! you want the annimation to work only for 10 secend then stop or what ? please to add some html and more detail in order to help

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not familiar with classList, I suggest to try this:

```
var classList = this.domNode.classList;
classList.add('widget-loading');
setTimeout(function(){classList.remove('widget-loading', 10000)});
```